# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable when creating RESTful API backend

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I am trying to test my Restful back end. When I run the code, I get the following error:     q = json_data['q']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Api.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_cors import CORS
from job_board_controller import JobBoardController

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
CORS(app)

class JobApi(Resource):
    def get(self):
        json_data = request.get_json()
        print(request.args)
        q = json_data['q']
        l = json_data['l']
        ip = json_data['ip']
        print(json_data)
        jobs = JobBoardController()
        jobs_reports = jobs.getJobListings(q, l, ip)
        return {'reports': jobs_reports}


api.add_resource(JobApi, '/job_board_api')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, the request being returned doesn't contain a response.

The `NoneType` error occurs because you are attempting to access an index `q` on a variable that is not an object, but is rather an empty variable.

If I were to define in code:

```
>>> a = None
>>> a['q']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

As you can see I get the same error.